# Winter Bash button blinks on reload

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash-2012

Every time I reload the page, this button takes a second longer to load and thus appears to blink:

[image]

It's not a huge issue, but since the "StackExchange" button appears instantly it gives me the impression this can be fixed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Winter Bash features are not on by default on Stack Overflow, and can be turned off anywhere. Since it is not applicable to all users on the network and will only be available for a short amount of time, it doesn't make sense to hard-code it into the structure of the site. All the Winter Bash and hats features are placed onto the site after the page load by JavaScript (if enabled), *none* of them are pre-loaded with the page.